# Fast summation of symmetric matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to sum all elements in a matrix `A` with dimension `n` times `n`. The matrix is symmetric and has 0s on the diagonal. The fastest way to do so that I have found is simply
`sum(A)`. However this seems wasteful since it doesn't use the fact that I only need to calculate the lower triangle of the matrix. However, `sum(tril(A, -1))` is significantly slower, and `sum(A[i, j] for i = 1:n-1 for j = i+1:n)` even more so. Is there a more efficient way to sum the matrix?

Edit: The solution by @AboAmmar performs well. Here is code (with summing the diagonal separately, something that can be removed if there is only zeros on the diagonal) to compare:

```
using BenchmarkTools
using LinearAlgebra

function sum_triu(A)
    m, n = size(A)
    @assert m == n
    s = zero(eltype(A))
    for j = 2:n
        @simd for i = 1:j-1
            s += @inbounds A[i,j]
        end
    end
    s *= 2
    for i = 1:n
        s += A[i, i]
    end
    return s
end

N = 1000
A = Symmetric(rand(0:9,N,N))
A -= diagm(diag(A))

@btime sum(A)
@btime 2 * sum(tril(A))
@btime sum_triu(A)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 2.7X faster than `sum` for n = 1000 matrix. Make sure to add a `@simd` before the loop and use `@inbounds`. Also, use the correct loop order for fast memory access.

```
function sum_triu(A)
    m, n = size(A)
    @assert m == n
    s = zero(eltype(A))
    for j = 1:n
        @simd for i = 1:j 
            s += @inbounds A[i,j]
        end
    end
    return 2 * s
end
```

Example run on my PC:

```
sum_triu(A) = 499268.7328022966
sum(A) = 499268.73280229873
   93.000 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  249.900 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: If this is faster than `sum(LowerTriangular)` then there is a PR to LinearAlgebra waiting to be written (BTW: was the `@inbounds` not critical?)

Comment: Yes, it is faster than `2 * sum(LowerTriangular(A))` by 8.25X times on my PC. And `@inbounds` wasn't critical.

Comment: But you must take care of the diagonal, if it is non-zero. As it is now, it will be counted twice.

Comment: Even if we take care of the diagonal, I still see a 2.4X factor against `sum` and a 7.3X factor against `sum(LowerTriangular(A))`.

Comment: The advantage against `LowerTriangular` is because  access to `LowerTriangular` goes through a filter (as in memory matrix doesn't conform to shape). Almost all matrix-wide operations should therefore have a fast Triangular version without the access filter. Almost seems enough to warrant keeping a boolean if it is 'safe' to do regular matrix op on memory of structured matrix, or to add another type for Triangular with different operation blend trade off (i.e. not store complete matrix for example)

Comment: @DanGetz In my tests, ```@inbounds``` will sometimes make substantial improvements (without it, the loop may take twice the time) and sometimes only very minor. Not clear when it makes a difference, seems stochastic to me.

Comment: @DNF See the minor change I made in the question to only count the diagonal once.

Comment: Try using `Threads.@threads`; It might outperform all of this.

Comment: @matnor, Does `@simd` work for triangular loops? If I remember, `@turbo`, which is more powerful, doesn't.

Comment: @DanGetz, I wonder if something in https://discourse.julialang.org/t/101667 or https://discourse.julialang.org/t/65498 could make it even more SIMD friendly.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
2 * sum(LowerTriangular(A))
```

```
help?> LA.LowerTriangular
  LowerTriangular(A::AbstractMatrix)

  Construct a LowerTriangular view of the matrix A.
```

`tril` creates a new matrix, which allocates memory. Since a `LowerTriangular`  is a `view` into the existing matrix, there's no memory allocation.

Comment: It does take up less memory, but it is actually slightly slower than ```tril``` and much slower than just summing the whole matrix.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose making a copy and zeroing things out in a loop (which is what `tril` does) is still a bit faster than having to check a condition for every single array access.